# Certbot renew certificates with autoprovided webroot

Tags: certbot

I have created some certificated using certbot's --standalone option but I want to renew them so I run (testing if will get renewed):

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

But for some domains I get the error

```
Attempting to renew cert from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.org.conf produced an unexpected error: Missing command line flag or config entry for this setting:
Select the webroot for example.org:
Choices: ['Enter a new webroot', '/var/www/ellakcy/']

(You can set this with the --webroot-path flag). Skipping.
```

So I want when I run `sudo certbot renew` to be able to autorenew my certificates without the need to provide a webroot path.

How I can do that?

Comment: Enter a new webroot, or specify one as it advised you to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is casued because on `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.org.conf` the certificate for it also apply on other domains as well so you need to specify the correct webroot for other domains as well in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.org.conf` at `[[webroot_map]]` as well.

For my domain `ellak.org.cy` that apply on other domains I have specified:

```
[renewalparams]
authenticator = webroot
installer = None
account=^an_account_hash^
[[webroot_map]]
ellak.org = /var/www/ellak.org/
www.ellak.org=/var/www/ellak.org
ellak.org.cy = /var/www/ellakcy/
www.ellak.org.cy = /var/www/ellakcy/
imap.ellak.org.cy = /var/www/mail_letencrypt/
mail.ellak.org = /var/www/mail_letencrypt/
mail.ellak.org.cy = /var/www/mail_letencrypt/
pop.ellak.org.cy = /var/www/mail_letencrypt/
pop3.ellak.org.cy = /var/www/mail_letencrypt/
smtp.ellak.org.cy = /var/www/mail_letencrypt/
guest8.ellak.gr = /var/www/ellakcy/
```

So the error has been removed.